# Comparing and dropping columns based on greater or smaller timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
id        started                    completed
1         2022-02-20 15:00:10.157    2022-02-20 15:05:10.044
```

and I have this other one `data`:

```
        timestamp                   x       y
    2022-02-20 14:59:47.329     16      0.0
    2022-02-20 15:01:10.347     16      0.2
    2022-02-20 15:06:35.362     16      0.3
```

what I wanna do is filter the rows in `data` where `timestamp > started and timestamp < completed` (which will leave me with the middle row only)

I tried to do it like this:

```
res = data[(data['timestamp'] > '2022-02-20 15:00:10.157')]
res = res[(res['timestamp'] > '2022-02-20 15:05:10.044')]
```

and it works.

But when I wanted to combine the two like this:

```
res = data[(data['timestamp'] > df['started']) and (data['timestamp'] < df['completed'])]
```

I get `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Can anyone please explain why and where am I doing the mistake? Do I have to convert to string the `df['started']` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here.

The first is the use of `and`. If you want to combine multiple masks (boolean array) with a "and" logic element-wise, you want to use `&` instead of `and`.

Then, the use of `df['started']` and `df['completed']` for comparing. If you use a debugger, you can see that
`df['started']` is a dataframe with its own indexes, the same for `data['timestamp']`. The rule for comparing, two dataframes are described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html). Essentially, you can compare only two dataframes with the same indexing. But here `df` has only one row, `data` multiple. Try convert your element from `df` as a non dataframe format. Using `loc` for instance.

For instance :

### Using masks

```py
n = 10
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.random.choice(np.array([*ascii_lowercase]), size=n),
        "y": np.random.normal(size=n),
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "max_val" : [0],
        "min_val" : [-0.5]
    }
)

df[(df.y < df2.loc[0, 'max_val']) & (df.y > df2.loc[0, 'min_val'])]
Out[95]: 
   x         y
2  v -0.055035
3  a -0.107310
5  d -0.097696
7  j -0.453056
8  t -0.470771
```

### Using query

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "max_val" : np.repeat(0, n),
        "min_val" : np.repeat(-0.5, n)
    }
)


df.query("y < @df2.max_val and y > @df2.min_val")
Out[124]: 
   x         y
2  v -0.055035
3  a -0.107310
5  d -0.097696
7  j -0.453056
8  t -0.470771
```

Comment: I tried using query and it didn't work, I got `ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (6069,), (1,))`, but using masks worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: To be fair, query can work only if `df2` has only one row. I will edit to be correct in all circonstances

Answer (score 0):

To make the comparisons, Pandas need to have the same rows count in both the dataframes, that's because a comparison is made between the first row of the `data['timestamp']` series and the first row of the `df['started']` series, and so on.

The error is due to the second row of the `data['timestamp']` series not having anything to compare with.

In order to make the code work, you can add for any row of `data`, a row in `df` to match against. In this way, Pandas will return a Boolean result for every row, and you can use the AND logical operator to get the results that are both True.

Pandas doesn't want Python's `and` operator, so you need to use the `&` operator, so your code will look like this:

```
data[(data['timestamp'] > df['started']) & (data['timestamp'] < df['completed'])]
```

Comment: when I apply this to my code I am getting `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`. The dtypes are datetime64[ns] both columns from both dataframes.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I changed my answer, the error comes from the comparison between data['timestamp'] and df['started'], indeed data['timestamp'] > df['started'] doesn't have any sense in pandas.

Comment: but I tried with you latest answer.

Comment: I'm not the autor of this answer, but the other one